# Activity_my.xml does not match, trying to follow android tutorial

Tags: xml, android-activity, android-studio

I'm following the android tutorial to making apps and am up to this page:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I've followed all the instructions however my "activity_my.xml" file shows this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

While the tutorial shows that the code should be this (or part of it, I'm not 100% sure):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't seem to find the above code in my "activity_my.xml" file. Can anyone show me what I've done wrong or if I've missed a step?

Edit:
Looking around the code that the tutorial says should be in "activity_my.xml" is instead in the "content_my.xml" file. Is this right?

Comment: I can't find `content_my.xml` file ... ... in `app/src/main/res/layout/` i only have `activity_my.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Easiest Solution is the following one:

Under Add an activity to , select Blank Activity and click Next.

Do not use "**Blank Activity**". Use "**Empty Activity**".

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry it's just using the support library provided by android and this `CoordinatorLayout` and others things are generated automatically by the android studio so you can follow material design. If you want to follow the tutorial, you can just copy paste the `LinearLayout` code.(`LinearLayout` was the default layout when you created new `Activity` along with layout in the old android studio)

Comment: For some reason this code is in content_my.xml instead of activity_my.xml?

Comment: So where do I copy and paste the LinearLayout code, in the activity xml? Won't there then be the same code in the activity and content xml or are they supposed to have the same?

Comment: If you copy paste the code in activity.xml you will only have LinearLayout (which is blank right now) . And if u paste  it in content.xml u will have toolbar and FloatingActionButton (which is right now present in your code) along with LinearLayout(which will appear in activity.xml because of "include" tag). If u want to follow tutorial just copy paste the code in activity.xml

Comment: Ok thanks but do I replace the code already in activity or do I post it within the android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout block?

Comment: I've tried copying and pasting the LinearLayout block of code in activity.xml but when I look at the design preview I can't see a button or text field like in the tutorial, instead I only see "Hello World" in the top right. Can you point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue.  Look in `content_main.xml`.  You will find the `<LinearLayout>` tag there and be able to proceed with the tutorial as written.